# Correr un batch como administrador

Tags: cmd, batch

Necesito crear un `batch` para reiniciar un servicio, debe que incluir las credenciales de administrador, algo como esto:

```
net stop miservicio [user][password]
net start miservicio [user][password]
set /p DUMMY = Presione enter para finalizar...
```

Intenté de diversas maneras y no he obtenido un resultado que me ayude.

De antemano, gracias comunidad y saludos.

Comment: Es más sencillo que obtengas respuestas útiles si pones las maneras en las que intentaste (o alguna que consideres más relevante) y el error que arroja.

Comment: En el task schenduler puede darles ejecutar con privilegios de administrador o con click derecho :v

Comment: yo respondería usando su, ya que no especificaste el sistema operativo

Answer (score 3):

Al momento de ejecutar el batch hazlo de la siguiente manera, es decir al final de tu código agrega lo siguiente:

```
runas /user:Administrator archivo.batch
```

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Trata anteponer a los credenciales el siguiente comando: `/user:` Quedaría algo así:

```
net stop miservicio /user:[user] [password]
net start miservicio /user:[user] [password]
set /p DUMMY = Presione enter para finalizar...
```

Answer (score 0):

Quizá con el comando 'sc'

```
sc stop "miservicio" obj= "[.\Usuario]" password= "[Password]"
sc start "miservicio" obj= "[.\Usuario]" password= "[Password]"
set /p DUMMY = Presione enter para finalizar...
```

**A tener en cuenta:**

- Solo se debe de sustituir Usuario y Password, no hay que quitar []
- Entre obj/password y el valor debe de haber un espacio para que
  funcione.